# unique values inside the object seperating

Tags: javascript

I have the below object which has three properties

```
 let input = {open_time: "1000",
        close_time: "2200",
        days: "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun"}
```

i need the output as

```
let output = [{key: 1, day: 'weekday', timings: '1000 - 2200'}, {key: 2, day: 'weekend', timings:'1000 - 2200'}]
```

Tried so far,

```
const WEEKDAYS = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"];

const dataMaker = (days, open_time, close_time) => {
  if (days) {
    const output = days.split(",").map((day, index) => {
      if (WEEKDAYS.includes(day)) {
        return {
          key: index,
          day: day,
          timings: `${open_time} - ${close_time}`,
        };
      }
      return {
        key: index,
        day: day,
        timings: `${open_time} - ${close_time}`,
      };
    });
    console.log(output);
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};
```

Comment: Your current attempt doesn't have the strings `'weekday'` or `'weekend'` anywhere in it, so I'm not sure how you expect the target output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a destructuring for the properties of the input object. Anfd you could take an object for the day types.

```js
const
    types = { weekday: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"], weekend: ["Sat", "Sun"] },
    dataMaker = ({ days, open_time, close_time }) => {
        if (!days) return [];
        const allDays = days.split(",");
        return Object
            .keys(types)
            .filter(type => types[type].some(day => allDays.includes(day)))
            .map((day, i) => ({ key: i + 1, day, timings: `${open_time} - ${close_time}` }));
    };


let input = {
  open_time: "1000",
  close_time: "2200",
  days: "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun"
}

console.log(dataMaker(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const WEEKDAYS = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"];
const WEEKENDDAYS = ["Sat", "Sun"];

const dataMaker = (days, open_time, close_time) => {
        if (!days) {
            return [];
        }
        return days.split(",").reduce((obj, day, index) => {
            if (WEEKDAYS.includes(day) || WEEKENDDAYS.includes(day)) {
                obj.push({
                    key: index,
                    day: WEEKDAYS.includes(day) ? 'weakday' : 'weekend',
                    timings: `${open_time} - ${close_time}`,
                });
            }
            return obj;
        }, []);
}

console.log(dataMaker("Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun","1000","2000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow Community is fast these days, lol!

My messy approach would be:

```
 let input = {open_time: "1000",
    close_time: "2200",
    days: "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun"};

function wtf(days, open_time, close_time) {
  let newOutput = [];
  let daysArray = days.split(',');
  let weekdays = daysArray.slice(0, 5);

  daysArray.forEach(day => {
  if(weekdays.includes(day)) {
    if(newOutput.length <= 0) {
      newOutput.push({
      key: 1,
      day: 'weekday',
      timings: `${open_time} - ${close_time}`
    });
    } 
  } else {
    if(newOutput.length < 2) {
      newOutput.push({
        key: 2,
        day: 'weekend',
        timings: `${open_time} - ${close_time}`
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return newOutput
}


console.log(wtf(input.days, input.open_time, input.close_time));
// let output = [
//   {key: 1, day: 'weekday', timings: '1000 - 2200'},
//   {key: 2, day: 'weekend', timings: '1000 - 2200'}
// ]
```